# Find the number of times that the difference of array values are equal to the number

Tags: java, array

I wrote the following code to answer this, but I am wondering if there is any better approach.

**For example**

If the following array is given:

> ```
> {10,21,34,45,56}
> ```

we should find the differentiate of each number with other values of the array and in case it is equals to 11 should increment the counter.

> ```
> 10-21=-11
> 10-34=-24
> 10-45=-35
> 10-56=-46
> 21-10=11     <
> 21-34=-13
> 21-45=-24
> 21-56=-35
> 34-10=24
> 34-21=13
> 34-45=-11
> 34-56=-22
> 45-10=35
> 45-21=24
> 45-34=11   <<
> 45-56=-11
> 56-10=46
> 56-21=35
> 56-34=22
> 56-45=11   <<<
> ```

**Code**

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       a.add(10);
       a.add(21);
       a.add(34);
       a.add(45);
       a.add(56);
      int number = 11;
      int counter = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
           for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++){
               if(j!=i){
                   int t = a.get(i) - a.get(j);
                   if(t == number){
                       System.err.println(a.get(i) +"-"+ a.get(j) + "=" + t);
                       counter++;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       System.err.println(counter);
    }
```

**Output**

The application is correctly showing the results but I am wondering if there is any other approach to the above solution.

> ```
> 21-10=11
> 45-34=11
> 56-45=11
> 3
> ```

Comment: Find the follow-up of this question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63110/follow-upfind-number-of-times-that-difference-of-array-values-are-equals-to-the

Comment: If your list is ordered, then you can break the inner loop as soon as "a.get(i) - a.get(j) > 11". Your inner loop can also start at i+1 instead of 0.

Comment: @the_lotus the optimized code is in follow-up link please check that out, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63110/follow-up-find-number-of-times-that-difference-of-array-values-are-equals-to-a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should look at the problem in a different way and come up with a simpler solution.

Try thinking at having a set of elements. What you want to know is if there is any pair of elements such that `a - b = x`.

You're given `x`, so for a given value of `a` in your set you should check whether it also contains `x + a`.

Your implementation should first move the content of the list to a `Set`. Then you have to iterate through the set and for each element `a` check if the set contains also `x + a`. If it is true then you should add `(a,b)` to your solution.

In your example, `x = 11`. If you consider `a = 10` you'll check if it contains `11 + 10 = 21`. It does so you can the pair `(21,10)` is a valid solution. Conversely, when you consider `a = 21`, you obtain `b = 32`, which is not part of the set and therefore you have to discard that pair.

```
int checkDifferences(Set<Integer> numbers, int difference) {
    int occurrences = 0;
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        if (numbers.contains(number + difference)) {
            occurrences++;
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

Comment: is not that wrong, as Set requires reference

Comment: I wrote this       Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
            a.add(10);
       a.add(21);
       a.add(34);
       a.add(45);
       a.add(56);
       int number = 11;
      int counter = 0;
    
          Iterator it = a.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()){
              Integer inte = (Integer) it.next();
              if(a.contains(inte + number)){
                  counter++;
              }
          }
      System.err.println(counter);
    }

Comment: Wait, I just added a method. Not the whole program. The reason I did is that it is always a good idea to separate things in different pieces instead of having everything on the main method. Putting everything together should be trivial.

Comment: great, would you please provide me with a full code for me to compare that with mine to learn more. thanks.

Comment: @Jack This answer should have given you a good starting point for how to improve your code. Reviewers have no obligation to provide you with the final result, I suggest that *you* spend some more time reading and understanding the answer and trying to make your code better with this answer in mind. It is, after all, *your* code.

Comment: The Set Contract does not allow duplicate items.. this is undesired behavior. Think `number = 0`... while your approach is intersting it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Exactly the way I would approach this.

Comment: A [MultiSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) could be used to make things more general.

Comment: I added a follow-up for it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63110/follow-upfind-number-of-times-that-difference-of-array-values-are-equals-to-the

Answer (score 7):

## Initialize `List`

Your `List<Integer>` can be initialized as the following:

```
 List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(10, 21, 34, 45, 56);
```

Actually, as you are dealing with a fixed-length size list, you can just use a regular array.

```
 int[] a = new int[]{ 10, 21, 34, 45, 56 };
```

## Spacing

I **strongly recommend** using more space in your for-loops:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
           if (j != i) {
```

Isn't that more readable? At least it is to me.

## Variable names

You are using way too many variable names with only one letter. I suggest renaming them like this:

- `a` --> `numbers`
- `i` --> `firstNumber`
- `j` --> `secondNumber`
- `t` --> `difference`

Answer (score 3):

The `int` values will be autoboxed here:

> ```
> List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
> a.add(10);
> a.add(21);
> // ...
> ```

And then unboxed here in every iteration of the nested `for for`:

> ```
> int t = a.get(i) - a.get(j);
> ```

To avoid that inefficiency it would be better to use a primitive array instead:

```
int[] a = { 10, 21, 34, 45, 56 };
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were to improve on your original solution, I will use `if ( j == i )` to eliminate one nested `if` and inline the arithmetic comparison together with incrementing `counter` as shown below:

```
private static void originalCheck( final List<Integer> list, final int difference ) {
    int counter = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < list.size() ; j++ ) {
            if ( j == i ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( list.get( i ) - list.get( j ) == difference && ++counter > 0 ) {
                System.err.println( String.format( "%d - %d = %d", list.get( i ), list.get( j ), difference ) );
            }
        }
    }
    System.err.println( counter );
}
```

If I have to implement an alternative solution, I will consider storing the numbers seen inside a `Map` so that I avoid traversing the full `List` twice. The inner `for`-loop will always start from the next index. The method to create the `Map` and the method to print the entries of the `Map` are shown below:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> checkDifference( final List<Integer> list, final int difference ) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = i + 1 ; j < list.size() ; j++ ) {
            final Integer first = list.get( i );
            final Integer second = list.get( j );
            final int diff = first - second;
            if ( Math.abs( diff ) == difference ) {
                result.put( diff > 0 ? first : second, diff > 0 ? second : first );
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static void printDifference( final Map<Integer, Integer> result ) {
    for ( final Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : result.entrySet() ) {
        final int difference = entry.getKey() - entry.getValue();
        System.err.println( String.format( "%d - %d = %d", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), difference ) );
    }
    System.err.println( result.size() );
}
```