# Follow-up: Find number of times that difference of array values are equals to a number

Tags: java

This question is follow-up to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63083/find-the-number-of-times-that-the-difference-of-array-values-are-equal-to-the-nu).

**Sample Calculation**

> ```
> 10-21=-11
> 10-34=-24
> 10-45=-35
> 10-56=-46
> 21-10=11     <
> 21-34=-13
> 21-45=-24
> 21-56=-35
> 34-10=24
> 34-21=13
> 34-45=-11
> 34-56=-22
> 45-10=35
> 45-21=24
> 45-34=11   <<
> 45-56=-11
> 56-10=46
> 56-21=35
> 56-34=22
> 56-45=11   <<<
> ```

**Code**

```
Set<Integer> tchars = new HashSet<>();
        tchars.add(10);
        tchars.add(21);
        tchars.add(34);
        tchars.add(45);
        tchars.add(56);
        int number = 11;
        int counter = 0;

        Iterator it = tchars.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Integer inte = (Integer) it.next();
            if (tchars.contains(inte + number)) {
                System.err.println(inte + " " + number);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.err.println(counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a Set is problematic.

First, as pointed out on the original question in @Vogel612's comment, it restricts duplicate values. Second, it also makes your code a lot messier, as you're now grabbing an `Iterator`, calling `.hasNext()`, and testing in a `while` loop instead of using more concise syntax.

I'd just use a `List<Integer>`, get rid of all the casts, and use a for-each style syntax instead of using the `Iterator`. Finally, `number` and `counter` aren't very meaningful as variable names in the context of this snippet.  If they are meaningful in the wider context of wherever this came from so-be-it, but I find something more along the lines of `difference` and `result` much clearer.

Something more like this:

```
List<Integer> tchars = Arrays.asList(10, 21, 34, 45, 56);
int difference = 11;
int result = 0;

for (int test : tchars) {
    if (tchars.contains(test + difference)) {
        System.err.println(test + " " + difference);
        result++;
    }
}

System.err.println(result);
```

Dead simple, and you can see immediately what it is doing.

Comment: What is a complexity of `tchars.contains()`?

Comment: This code doesn't work, try it on `10, 10, 21, 34, 45, 56` for example.

Comment: @mjolka Good catch on the sign, fixed.

Comment: @vnp - [Time complexity is linear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), "roughly speaking".

Comment: Using `List.contains` is not a very good suggestion for performance. The overall complexity of this code is O(n^2). It is possible to do a O(n) solution.